# graph (node and edges) in access

Tags: ms-access, graphics

We've got a pretty complex graph in an Access DB stored as nodes (node1, node2, etc.) and edges between the nodes (n1->n2 etc.).

We'd like to visualize this in an MS Access application. What "graphics packages" would you suggest? How can these be integrated into Access? We're currently using Access 2002.

NOTE: A tree control is not sufficient as we have a more general graph (if you displayed our graph as a tree one node would occur multiple times).

Comment: Look at GLEE, I think you can stil get hold of the free version (http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/f1303e46-965f-401a-87c3-34e1331d32c5/default.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you want your Graph visualisation to do, if it is just a picture then you could try using a command line based package like GraphViz.  You'd just need to write a macro to invoke GraphViz, output your Graph in the DOT syntax to the GraphViz command line and then display the generated image in Access using a Form.

If you want an interactive visualisation of your Graph I've never used any such package myself so can't recommend one but I'm sure there are some out there.

Comment: A static display of the graph would be fine, so I think I'll try your suggestion ...

Answer (score 0):

I've always looked at Excel as being an excellent data visualization and graphing tool in conjunction with Access.   (Of course the Excel folks soemtimes don't appreciate my attitude.) Can you easily do the graph in Excel?

Modules: Sample Excel Automation
http://www.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0006.htm
Modules: Transferring Records to Excel with Automation
http://www.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0035.htm

Comment: Excel would be well suited if my data was a "chart" (like a line or bar chart), but not for a complex node&edge graph. Just one of many problems I see: How would I lay out the nodes in order to minimize the number of edges crossing?

Comment: Sorry, not a clue when it comes to node/edge graphing.